# Javascript class declaration scope confusion

Tags: javascript, scope

I run the code below in the latest chrome console.

I thought that the `Test` class would be declared in `root`'s scope, so I could then access the constructor via string, yet this is not the case. Could someone please explain, how do I create a new instance with `'Test'`?

```
(() => {
  let root = this
  class Test {}
  console.log( root['Test'] )
})()
```

Comment: class declarations do **not** get hoisted. You should also read up on lexical scoping created by arrow functions

Comment: @Dummy Out of curiosity, what scope do they get added to then? They need to have a scope right?

Comment: `Test` will be scoped to the enclosing arrow function because you used arrow function, this is called lexical scoping, but once again, because you used arrow function `let root = this` will refer to the enclosing instance instead which does not have `Test` as a member obviously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the class to `this` because it is not attached by default.
Then you will be able to access it as Object property.

See code below:

```js
(() => {
  this.Test = class Test {
    name() {
      return "Hi 5";
    }
  }
  console.log('Name is ', new this['Test']().name())
  console.log('Or using window ')
  console.log('Name is ', new window['Test']().name())
})()
```

Comment: Where does the class normally reside, if not in `this` or `window`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
(() => {
  let root = this;
  class Test {}
  this.Test = Test;
  console.log(root['Test'])
})()
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit?

Comment: declaring Class Test will not bind it to current context (this). It is only binded to lexical scope. You need to explicitly bind it to this if you want to have it accesible thru this.

Comment: it is excatly the same as you declare function Test() {}. It will not be bind to 'this'. unless you do this.Test = Test or this.Test = function () {}